# How to save the image uri when button back is pressed?

Tags: android

i want to save that image the user uploaded to the imageview but i press back and the activity is destroyed image uri is removed how can i keep it please?

```
    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (uri != null)
        {
            outState.PutParcelable("uri", uri);

        }
    }

    protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        uri = (Android.Net.Uri)savedInstanceState.GetParcelable("uri");
        _imageView.SetImageURI(uri);

    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.User_Account);

        button.Click += ButtonOnClick;

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            uri = (Android.Net.Uri)savedInstanceState.GetParcelable("uri");
            _imageView.SetImageURI(uri);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your saving state methods not getting called because system pop this activity from tack, cause you closed is intentionally. (The same thing happens when you call finish()). So you should override `onBackPressed` method and store this url in some kind of memory cache or persistent cache(Shared prefs, DB, file)

Answer (score 0):

To send the URI back to previous activity, go for [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

To save the Uri permanently in your app even if closed, see [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)